# How do I block site to specific users or IP?

Tags: wordpress, comments, ip-address, spam-blocker

I have been running a website with WordPress blog since few time.

I have been receiving email reporting that few specific address has been posting un-related comments in my website. I am receiving like one email per minute from same IP address.

So since the IP address is posting un-related comments I would like to block it.

But don't know how?

Its something like: `178.238.232.234`, `234.232.238.178.static.giga-dns.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block them using htaccess by putting something like this in the htaccess file in your root Wordpress directory:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 178.238.232.234
```

Comment: does it works for: IP: 178.238.232.234 , 234.232.238.178.static.giga-dns.com too

Comment: I updated my answer to block the specific IP address that is causing your problem.